# Touch ID does not work in many cases

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-id

I have the Macbook Pro 2018 13" (Intel) and I use the Touch ID often, but I discovered that in all subsequent updates since Mojave to Sonoma (5.x update) many apps and still macOS itself ask for a password. The same applies when I bought another Macbook Pro (the 2021 14" M1 edition) two years ago.

I checked all checkmarks for using Touch ID (see attached screenshot), but in these cases, a password is still required:

Unlocking the MBP after 48 hours or after a reboot (which is correct according to documentation), but sometimes it already occurs the next morning or even a few hours later without shutting down or rebooting.

This is very annoying, particularly since Apple is advocating a password-less use of devices. How can I work around this that it only asks for a password after a reboot or after more than 48 hours in a locked state?

Moreover, many third-party and even built-in apps don't support Touch ID. Why is there not a setting where the user can select per app that all password prompts are replaced by Touch ID, such as the per-app base of e.g. access to the file system?

I found one app called [SEKey](https://github.com/sekey/sekey) which allows using Touch ID in the terminal such as SSH'ing into other servers or using `sudo` for rooted commands. Unfortunately, this has not been maintained since 2017, but despite being Intel-only, it does work on an M1 Mac.

[image: Screenshot of the Touch ID & Password settings]

Comment: "...but sometimes it already occurs the next morning or even a few hours later without shutting down or rebooting" Are you sure your book hasn't rebooted due to something like a panic?  You could have a look for panic logs: /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Retired/panic-full-xxxx.panic

Comment: After reboot and after 48 hours is to expected: but after a few hours is not. Can you provide more data on what is asking for authentication, and when? However, I don't think you're going to get round Apple's security procedures easily.

Comment: Also: which built-in apps don't use TouchID? I think it may depend on the API that the app is calling -- older ones might not offer TouchID.

Comment: The logs /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Retired/ are empty.

"Also: which built-in apps don't use TouchID?"
Firefox 118
Brave (Chromium 118)
Forklift 4
They all are recent (less than 2 months old) and prompt for passwords for ssh authentication or master password of browser.